# How to download pdf generated in laravel, from vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5

I have the following function in laravel for the generation of a pdf

```
public function download_agreement(Request $request){
        try{
           /*  $items = DB::table("items")->get();
                    view()->share('items',$items); */
            if ($request->has('download')) {
            $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.agency.agreement');
            return $pdf->download('pdfview.pdf');
        }
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.agency.agreement');
        return view('pdfview');
        }
        catch(\Exception $error){
            Log::error('[RegistrantsController] error in send_agreement ' . $error);
            return response()->json(['code' => 403, 'message' => 'Something went wrong']);
        }
    }
```

And then I'm doing the following:

```
downloadAgreement() {
      console.log("DOWNLOAD");
      let sendData = {
        uuid: this.$route.params.uuid,
        email: "email@gmail.com",
        download: true
      };
     axios
    .post(config.routePrefix + "/agency/download_agreement", sendData)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
      console.log(url);
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = url;
      link.setAttribute("download", "file.pdf");
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

I generated the pdf and managed to download it. The problem I have is that it shows me the blank pdf.
In my .blade file:

```
@extends('pdf.layout')
@section('style')
<style>
    .agreement-text {
        margin-left: 7%;
        margin-right: 7%;
    }
    .sign-line{
      align-self: center;
      width: 60%;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    .ql-align-justify{
        text-align: justify;
    }
    .ql-align-center{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .header-line{
        border: none;
        height: 3px;
        color: #a1d138 ;
        background-color: #a1d138 ;
    }
</style>
@stop
@section('content')
    <header>
        {{-- <img style="width: 30%;" src="{{ config('arm.arm_app.email_pdf_logo') }}"> --}}
        <hr class="header-line">
    </header>

    <div class="agreement-text">
        TEST TEST TEST TEST
    </div>


    <div class="img-div">
        {{-- <img class="img-center" src="{{$sign}}"> --}}
    </div>

    <div class="img-div">
        <hr class="sign-line">
        Nombre
    </div>
@stop
```

At the moment I am not sending any data, I simply want to generate a pdf with text easily

Comment: An internal server error is always accompanied by a specific error message. Find it in your logs and figure out what it says.

Comment: I already generate it and download it but it shows it blank. I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$pdf->download` already returns the correct headers, the easiest solution would be to display a link to that URL to the user which they can click. Just make sure to open it in a new tab if there could be unsaved content on the page, e.g. a form.

You could also open a popup using JS. As far as I know all browsers will show a save prompt and then close the tab.

Comment: I already generate it and download it but it shows it blank. I have edited my question

Comment: I meant a link directly to your `download_agreement` page, but now I see that it's a post request so that won't work.. If you manually navigate to the URL generated with `createObjectURL` (copy-paste into address bar) does it work? And are you triggering the `downloadAgreement()` function from a user interaction?